# Disabling GPS LocationListener calls onProviderDisabled on GPS and Network

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, locationlistener

as the questions says, when i disable the GPS on the device, the function `onProviderDisabled(String Provider)` gets called twice (for gps and then for network). but i still get network positions `onLocationChanged(Location location)`

why is that?

also when enabling back the GPS, `onProviderEnabled` gets called twice.. for GPS and for network

```
LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER)
    };

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
{

  @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        globalVariables.DebugLogging("here"+location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        if (provider.equals("gps")) {
            GPS_ENABLED = false;
        }
        else
        {
            NETWORK_ENABLED = false;
        }
        globalVariables.DebugLogging( "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        if (provider.equals("gps")) {
            GPS_ENABLED = true;
        }
        else
        {
            NETWORK_ENABLED = true;
        }
        globalVariables.DebugLogging( "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe onLocationChanged could still get called on some phones making a distinction between GSM & GPS issued location updates. That's just a supposition though. Edit : On my N5, turning location off cuts everything. Are the updates meaningful ?

Comment: no you are right turning location off will cut everything

Comment: Do the location updates return coherent results when GPS is disabled ? Might be useful to check whether Google Play Services are up to date too.